# ASP.NET Core Blazor WASM Cannot Register Service

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, blazor, blazor-webassembly, webassembly

im trying to make an AccountController for my Page.
i just cannot seem to understand the whole service & injecting things.

I have made a Controller

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class AccountController : ControllerBase
{
    List<User> _users = new List<User>()
    {
        new User()
        {
            Name= "Nico",
            Id = 0
        }
    };
    // GET api/<ValuesController>/5
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public User GetUser(int id)
    {
        return _users.Where(x => x.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
    }

    // POST api/<ValuesController>
    [HttpPost]
    public void RegisterUser([FromBody] User user)
    {

    }

    // DELETE api/<ValuesController>/5
    [HttpDelete("{id}")]
    public void DeleteUser(int id)
    {
        _users.Remove(_users.Where(x => x.Id == id).FirstOrDefault());
    }
}
```

i am calling this Controller from my Service

```
 public class AccountService : IAccountService
    {
        private readonly HttpClient _http;

        public AccountService(HttpClient http)
        {
            _http = http;
        }

        public async Task<User> GetUser(int id)
        {
           return await _http.GetFromJsonAsync<User>("Account");
        }
    }

    public interface IAccountService
    {
        Task<User> GetUser(int id);
    }
```

and now im in the **CLIENT** Programm.cs as there is a comment "add services to container".

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddHttpClient<IAccountService>();

var app = builder.Build();
```

from my Page im trying to inject the service and call the get function

```
@inject Opta24.Client.Services.IAccountService IAccountService;

@code{
    private User? User;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        User = await IAccountService.GetUser(0);
    }
}
```

now my Page does NOT render, it has an unhandled error stating the Service is not registred.
What am i doing wrong? Its blazor wasm asp.net hosted, its so much at one take damn.
here is the error message

> crit:
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
> Unhandled exception rendering component: Cannot provide a value for property 'IAccountService' on type
> 'Opta24.Client.Shared.MainLayout'. There is no registered service of
> type 'Opta24.Client.Services.IAccountService'.
> System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot provide a value for property
> 'IAccountService' on type 'Opta24.Client.Shared.MainLayout'. There is
> no registered service of type
> 'Opta24.Client.Services.IAccountService'.

Comment: It appears that you didn't register `Opta24.Client.Services.IAccountService` with your IoC container.

Comment: Sorry what? I dont think i have another point of "reaching" services in the project

Comment: I'm a Blazor Server guy, not WASM, but don't you need `builder.Services.AddSingleton<IAccountService, AccountService>();`? And then you would `@inject IAccountService AccountService;` and call `User = await AccountService.GetUser(0);`.

Comment: I actually fixed it just now... Idk all tutorials and the doc say register it in the server. God Damn i just have registered it with AddScope to the Client and it works...

Comment: Now i have an error that "<" is not the expected start for a value. even tho i havent actually called anything else except "creating" the service. But i guess im gonna fix that now lmaoooo